# Changing MVC local DB to SQL DB on release

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, database-migration

I am having an issue when trying to release my MVC application to a production environment, switching from the localdb to a SQL production DB.

It seems to still want to access the localDB even after i changed my defaultconnection connection string in the release web.config. Its trying to access the localDB everytime i try to login/register a user on the released package ( should be noted that it works perfectly fine when debugging )

Please see below code snippets

Web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Questionnaire-20200826090735.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Questionnaire-20200826090735;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Questionnaire_managementEntities" connectionString="......" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="CWDataSetsEntities" connectionString="........" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.9.0" newVersion="3.1.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

web.release.config

```
    <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--
    In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of
    "connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator
    finds an attribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB"
        connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  -->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
         connectionString="data source=lonvmdp02;initial catalog=Questionnaire_login;user id=cwdataagent;password=Pa$$w0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
    <!--
      In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire
      <customErrors> section of your Web.config file.
      Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the
      <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
    -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Manage Controller

```
[Authorize]
    public class ManageController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public ManageController()
        {
        }

        public ManageController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            }
            private set 
            { 
                _signInManager = value; 
            }
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }
}
```

IdentityConfig

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Questionnaire.Models;

namespace Questionnaire
{
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    // Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }

    // Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

IdentityModel

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace Questionnaire.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public bool is_verified { get; set; }
        public string Verified_at { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Country", this.Country.ToString()));
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("is_verified", this.is_verified.ToString()));
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

IdentityExtension ( extension to enable a few more identity functions )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;

namespace Questionnaire.Models.Extensions
{
    public static class IdentityExtensions
    {
        public static string GetCountry(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("Country");
            // Test for null to avoid issues during local testing
            return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
        }

        public static string Is_Verified(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("is_verified");
            if(claim==null)
            {
                return "NULL";
            }
            return (claim.Value) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Migration Configuration ( did this to sync applicationdbconcext with localdb to fix an error )

```
namespace Questionnaire.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Questionnaire.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            ContextKey = "Questionnaire.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
        }

        protected override void Seed(Questionnaire.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
        }
    }
}
```

Migration record - TestMigration

```
namespace Questionnaire.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    
    public partial class testmigration : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Country", c => c.String());
            AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "is_verified", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
            AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Verified_at", c => c.String());
        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Verified_at");
            DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "is_verified");
            DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Country");
        }
    }
}
```

Migration record - initialcreate

```
namespace Questionnaire.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    
    public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetRoles",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");
            
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUserRoles",
                c => new
                    {
                        UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        RoleId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.RoleId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId)
                .Index(t => t.RoleId);
            
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUsers",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                        EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        PasswordHash = c.String(),
                        SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                        PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                        PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                        LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");
            
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUserClaims",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        ClaimType = c.String(),
                        ClaimValue = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId);
            
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUserLogins",
                c => new
                    {
                        LoginProvider = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        ProviderKey = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.LoginProvider, t.ProviderKey, t.UserId })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId);
            
        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "RoleId", "dbo.AspNetRoles");
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserNameIndex");
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "RoleId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetRoles", "RoleNameIndex");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserLogins");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserClaims");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserRoles");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetRoles");
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to see any other part of the code please let me know.
Like i said. it works perfectly using debugging, however when i try to release and run over IIS, its still trying to access the Local DB

[Release Error on server localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAhhB.png)

Comment: I have a suspicion that its the Rolemanager that is giving an issue, but i do not know how to change the Role connection string after i enable roles in web.config

Answer (score 1):

adding this to my web.config,

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomizedRoleProvider">
          <providers>
            <add name="CustomizedRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
```

as well as running the aspnet_regsql command in my visual studio command line and going through the setup, solved my issue.

The regsql command adds a bunch of tables that im not using, but it also added some stored procedures that my login db needed.

Answer (score 0):

Account Controller ( i use register2 function to do registrations )

```
[Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public AccountController()
        {
        }

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            }
            private set 
            { 
                _signInManager = value; 
            }
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register2(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Questionnaire_managementEntities db = new Questionnaire_managementEntities();
                var userexist = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == model.Email).Select(x => x);

                //if(userexist.Count()==0)
                //{
                //    Questionnaire.User Newuser = new User();
                //    Newuser.Country = model.Country;
                //    Newuser.Email = model.Email;
                //    Newuser.Is_verified = false;
                //    var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                //    var password = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(model.Password);
                //    var hash = md5.ComputeHash(password);
                //    Newuser.Password = hash.ToString() ;

                //    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    ModelState.AddModelError("", "User Account Already Exist");
                //}

                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Country = model.Country };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                string[] users =  {user.UserName};
                
                IdentityUserRole roles = new IdentityUserRole();
                roles.RoleId = "2";
                roles.UserId = user.Id;
                user.Roles.Add(roles);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
}
```